# Creating guest user for ssh login

Tags: ssh

Is it  possible to create  a user  that can log  in to
one's ssh server and chat,  but is restricted from any
other activity,  i.e. cannot use any  significant disk
space, cannot  access hardware  (speakers, microphone,
camera),  and  is  perhaps   even  limited  to  a  low
CPU-percentage?

Comment: For giving you a proper answer, I need more information. Is that chat some CLI program like ircii, talk etc.?

Comment: @Garex, I thought talk or write.

Comment: ok that is great to know because then you can specify the allowed commands in the authorized_keys directly after the key that is allowed:

# authorized_keys
command="/usr/bin/talk" <SSH Key>

But with that you could also specify a shell script as allowed command you provide some input with it. 

Please, if you use OpenSSH, have also a look into the AuthorizedKeysCommand in your sshd_config file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the purpose is only to support a single application which does all of its input via `STDIN`/`STDOUT`, you should be able to use the old UNIX trick of specifying that program as the user's shell.

First off, you would need to create a user account for the person; I don't believe you would be able to use the built in "Guest account" since not only do I think it exists only when someone uses the GUI login (read: SSH won't trigger it), but also I don't think there is a concept of default shell for guest.

Second, you need to add the specific program (say `/bin/ttychat`) to the `/etc/shells` file. Finally, you need to specify that "shell" as the default for the account you created.

The idea is that when the SSH account logs in, it will redirect all `STDIN`/`STDOUT` for the session to the shell you specified. When the program terminates, it should close the connection as well.

I found an unrelated question on Stack Exchange showing how to add custom shells to OSX [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/453236/how-to-set-my-default-shell-on-mac).

Comment: Any idea if it's possible to specify the programme with arguments? if I try I get `non-standard shell` error msg.

Comment: I tried using a script containing `#!/bin/bash` and `exec write lawrence`, which worked.  Can you confirm that there is no way of breaking out of this and gaining access to the shell?

Comment: @Lawrence, I'm not going to state that it is fool-proof and that you should interpret this mechanism is entirely secure; the script/program you ran as the "shell" needs to be solid and not fail or expose holes. However, I will state that if /bin/ttychat (from example) is the user's shell, exiting that program wouldn't invoke interactive bash but rather close the SSH session.